# Passing UITableView's with parsing XML

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I am parsing XML and I select from the UITablevView but I have an issue that how I am going to change the link on each selection?

For example;

[www.example.com/test12.php?d=0](http://www.example.com/test12.php?d=0)

[www.example.com/test12.php?d=1&il=istanbul](http://www.example.com/test12.php?d=1&il=istanbul)

[www.example.com/test12.php?d=2&il=istanbul&ilce=kadikoy](http://www.example.com/test12.php?d=2&il=istanbul&ilce=kadikoy)

How can I change the d= and il= and ilce= value on each select on the UITableView?

I have write this but couldn't go further.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
NSString *cellText = selectedCell.textLabel.text;

NSString *linkID = @"http://example/test12.php?d=@%&il=@%";

NSLog(@"%@ Selected", cellText);
}
```

---

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
 UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

containerObject = [objectCollection objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                  reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

// Set up the cell...
cell.textLabel.text = containerObject.city;
return cell;
}
```

Thanks from now.

Comment: Explain what is in the table view, how it relates to the parameters and where the parameters are stored...

Comment: What is (1,1,2), istanbul and kadikoy. Where are this store? in NSArary in Dictionary or somewhere else?

Comment: Thanks @Wain I am showing city's at first and when one of them selected it shows the province and then places... I am not storing anything I am just showing data. Please return to me.

Comment: You definitely are storing data. And you're using 3 different table views? Which means you're creating and configuring each new table with some details about what was selected. Show the code.

Comment: Thanks @CRDave. When I select one of them it have to change the link so I can show the other result. 1 is only for city and when 2 city is selected need province and 3 city and province is selected need place.

Comment: @Wain Am I need to create 3 different table? Normally I am planing on reloading the table on each time. Which code side do you want I will put it now.

Comment: At least cellForRowAtIndexPath code. Need to understand what your source data is and you haven't described it yet. Reloading the same table gives complex code. I'd (probably) use 3 table views with different controllers and a navigation controller...

Comment: Ok, so `objectCollection` is your data store, at least for cities. What it is, an array of dictionaries? What keys are in the dictionaries?

Comment: @Wain I can't show all the code here it is not allowing me. All city's and others stored in the ObjectCollection. I can show you all the code if you want via giving me an address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd do this with 3 different table view controllers and a navigation controller. Doing it this way keeps each controller simple and allows for a nice animation between drill levels so the user has a sense of what has changed.

Your data structure should be an array which contains dictionaries for each city. Each city dictionary contains an array of province dictionaries. Each province dictionary contains an array of places. (Technically these could be separate data structures and each holds a reference to the data that's required instead but let's keep it simple just now).

Each table view controller should take an array as its source of data. It should also take some other parameter, which could be the generated link so far.

The city view controller displays the list of city names (as you have it currently). When a row is selected, it gets the appropriate dictionary for the city, gets the array of provinces, creates a province view controller and passes it the provinces list. It also adds the city component to the link and passes that to the province view controller.

When a province is selected, the same process as above is followed.

When a place is selected, the final link component can be added and the link is now complete and can be used.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you fetch the model from your row and insert the values via stringWithFormat:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    YourModel* containerObject = [objectCollection objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];    
    NSString *linkID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://example/test12.php?d=%@&il=%@", containerObject.var1, containerObject.var2]; 
}
```